# Strange characters when using pound sign

Tags: html, codeigniter

I've already got this line in my header..

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I have an input form and when I enter a pound sign £ it's coming out with a strange character before it. The values are stored in the database and then displayed but the problem seems to be before we even get to the database.

If I submit my form and then print_r the $_POST array I get:

[field2_title] => Â£ Question

I thought the issue might be with the code igniter $this->input->post() function but it's happening before then. Other than adding the meta tag which I've already done I'm not sure what else to try?

I have also tried this..

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: Perhaps in your view, add the following code:

<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8'); ?>

Comment: Without putting/using the above lines, what are the HTTP headers being sent to the browser from the server?

Comment: dkrape that worked thanks! If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

In your view, try adding the following code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```